# How to change the size of a CapsuleCollider2D with code, Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, size

my character has a CapsuleCollider2D and now I want to change the height of the collider when he crouches. I found different ways for BoxColliders2D and normal CapsuleCollider 3D but not for the 2D version.
Thanks in advance

~Julian

Comment: in the code or in the editor? what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the capsule collider size with:

```
myCapsuleCollider.size
```

You can change it like so:

```
myCapsuleCollider.size = new Vector2(desiredWidth,desiredHeight);
```

Just replace `desiredWidth` and `desiredHeight` with the values you want the character collider to resize to.

Unity Docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CapsuleCollider2D.html

Comment: Thank you for your help bro. I accidently referred to a normal CapsuleCollider and not a CapsuleCollider2D